# What is the status of shuls turned into churches

Tags: synagogue, ymoth-hamoshiach

We all know when moshiach arrives all shuls will go to Eretz Yisroel

What will be with the many
shuls that were confiscated and turned
into churches and are still around?

What will happen with these beautiful shuls (after the
avoda zoro is decimated)?

Comment: an example is:   dome of the rock on the makom  hamikdosh.  the dome will disintegrate. and the makom  will become……..

Comment: The dome of the rock isn't a church. It isn't even a mosque.

Comment: "_We all know_..." Do we?

Comment: Who says the shuls will become churches? Wouldn't the churches become true monotheistic churches or shuls for non-Jews anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the question ONLY about confiscated shuls because if a shul  was sold  voluntarily (a serious question in halacha about when that may be done) due to a factor like the neighborhood deteriorated  it unquestionably loses its status as a shul.

The Gemora Megilah 26 A says:

אָמַר רָבָא לֹא שָׁנוּ אֶלָּא שֶׁלֹּא מָכְרוּ שִׁבְעָה טוֹבֵי הָעִיר בְּמַעֲמַד אַנְשֵׁי
הָעִיר אֲבָל מָכְרוּ שִׁבְעָה טוֹבֵי הָעִיר בְּמַעֲמַד אַנְשֵׁי הָעִיר אֲפִילּוּ
לְמִישְׁתֵּא בֵּיהּ שִׁיכְרָא שַׁפִּיר דָּמֵי

The Mechaber OC 153:9 says

כשמוכרים אנשי הכפר ב"ה יכולים למכרו ממכר עולם והלוקח יעשה בו מה שירצה חוץ ממרחץ ובורסקי ובית הטבילה ובית  הלוקח אפי' אלו הארבעה דברים etc.

*When the residents of a village sell a synagogue, they may sell it as a permanent sale; and the buyer may make anything he wants with it - except for a bathhouse, a tannery, a ritual bathhouse, or a bathroom. But if the seven distinguished men of the city (ie. trustees) sold it in the presence of the residents of the city, the buyer can make [it into] even these four things*

If however it was confiscated and made into a church then it should return to be a shul when Mosiach comes. That is part of the redemption of Mosiach! Even if the church makes significant changes to the building. A person can not make the items of  someone else forbidden by worshipping it and even if a non-Jew improves a stolen item they still have to return it (Rambam Gezila 5:2)

Comment: there is also a issue ……with a church turning into a shul or beth middrash etc .

Comment: @user19400 Rav Moshe Feinstein writes (OC1:49, to Rabbi Hanover in NY) that he'll never give a heter to turn a church into a shul. Sure enough after that one responsum, it appears no one asked him about that again. (At least not that we see in the Igros.)

Comment: Thanks….so the question is these in the question,were shuls that were forced into churches

Comment: Rav Moshe's own Yeshiva (The Yeshiva of Staten Island) was a former Catholic girls school with the former sanctuary being used as the Beis Medrash. For the first few years they learned and used the gym as the Beis Medrash but ultimately Rav Moshe allowed them to use the sanctuary as the Beis Medrash

Comment: @Schmerel thanks. He indicates in the teshuva that it had been done before him and he wouldn't challenge those places that already did so, but he wouldn't give a heter to freshly convert any existing churches.

Comment: my question is …..what would of r moshe said if the church was originally a shul